# GORM low level api finds object (Mongodb record) but its still NULL?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I have code like this in a controller method:

```
            DB db = mongoClient.getDB("twcdb");
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection('countrycodes')
        println coll.findOne()
        println coll.findOne().class
```

and I get this output at the console:

```
[_id:539848b2119918654e7e90c3, Country:Bermuda, Alpha2:BM, Aplha3:BMU, Numeric:60, FIPS:BD, IGA:Model 2]
null
```

So how can it be that it finds a record but its class is null? Is this because this record isn't modeled by any of my domain classes? It does recognize the record's individual fields as Strings which I just tested but the record overall is classed NULL? How, why?

Comment: don't call ``class`` but ``getClass()``

Comment: @cfrick Thanks that worked. Now I get this class com.mongodb.BasicDBObject. Now how come the plain class() method didn't work here? Just curious. If you want to post as answer I'd be glad to mark it the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should never call `class` on an object as there are scenarios where this could fail (e.g. `getProperty('class')` gets called or you are on a "mapish" object, which means that groovy will call `get('class')` for you -- which is the case for the `BasicDBObject` (subsubclass of a `LinkedHashMap`)).  always use `getClass()`